# Person Account creation AND Campaign Member activity in journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, person-accounts, campaign-member, smart-capture

enter image description hereIn SFMC, I have created a DE and CloudPage with Smart Capture form, to collect email address and some other fields. This CloudPage is the entry/trigger for a journey. What I want to do with the journey, is look up and update or create a Person Account in Service Cloud, but I also want to add that person to a (Sales Cloud) campaign. This last part is the issue.

I have left 15 mins window between the two activities (Person Account creation and addition to that account to a campaign) and I have tried both Campaign Member and Object Activity (in both Create New and Find & Update versions) but still I get the same soft error attached. For the Contact ID I have tried both 'SalesforceObjectID' from MC and 'Assign to the Person in the Journey' but neither seems to work.

I have read all relevant questions here but can't find the option that works. Does anyone have a solution to this??

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: it would be help if you posted screenshots of your configuration  of object aactivity and campaign member in the journey

Comment: here that are..